# SonarQube Runner vs Scanner

Tags: sonarqube, sonar-runner

What is the difference btw Sonar Runner and Sonar Scanner?.

And which version of "Sonarqube" and Sonar runner is required for JDK7?

Answer (score 48):

Answer is very simple: **"Runner"** is the old name for **"Scanner"**.

Everything you need to know about the different SonarQube Scanners is available on the [Scanners](http://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SCAN) part of the official documentation.

If you're stuck to `Java 7`, then you can use:

- SonarQube Runner (sonar-runner) up to version 5.5 of SonarQube
- SonarQube Scanner (sonar-scanner) 2.6.1