# Getting error while run sonar-scanner: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/sonar/batch/bootstrapper/LogOutput$Level

Tags: sonarqube, sonar-runner, sonarqube-scan

```
sonar-scanner -X
19:49:25.192 INFO: Scanner configuration file: /usr/local/Cellar/sonar-scanner/3.1.0.1141/libexec/conf/sonar-scanner.properties

19:49:25.211 INFO: SonarQube Scanner 3.1.0.1141
19:49:25.212 INFO: Java 1.8.0_131 Oracle Corporation (64-bit)
19:49:25.212 INFO: Mac OS X 10.13 x86_64
19:49:25.363 DEBUG: keyStore is : 
19:49:25.363 DEBUG: keyStore type is : jks
19:49:25.363 DEBUG: keyStore provider is : 


19:49:25.589 DEBUG: Create isolated classloader...
19:49:25.597 DEBUG: Start temp cleaning...
19:49:25.607 DEBUG: Temp cleaning done
19:49:25.607 DEBUG: Execution getVersion
```

- List item

  19:49:25.623 INFO: EXECUTION FAILURE
  19:49:25.623 INFO: ------------------------------------------------------------------------
  19:49:25.623 INFO: Total time: 0.452s
  19:49:25.648 INFO: Final Memory: 4M/123M
  19:49:25.648 INFO: ------------------------------------------------------------------------
  19:49:25.648 ERROR: Error during SonarQube Scanner execution
  java.lang.BootstrapMethodError: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/sonar/batch/bootstrapper/LogOutput$Level
      at org.sonarsource.scanner.api.internal.batch.DefaultBatchFactory.createBatch(DefaultBatchFactory.java:35)
      at org.sonarsource.scanner.api.internal.batch.BatchIsolatedLauncher.execute(BatchIsolatedLauncher.java:46)
      at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
      at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
      at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
      at org.sonarsource.scanner.api.internal.IsolatedLauncherProxy.invoke(IsolatedLauncherProxy.java:60)
      at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy0.execute(Unknown Source)
      at org.sonarsource.scanner.api.EmbeddedScanner.doExecute(EmbeddedScanner.java:171)
      at org.sonarsource.scanner.api.EmbeddedScanner.execute(EmbeddedScanner.java:128)
      at org.sonarsource.scanner.cli.Main.execute(Main.java:111)
      at org.sonarsource.scanner.cli.Main.execute(Main.java:75)
      at org.sonarsource.scanner.cli.Main.main(Main.java:61)
  Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/sonar/batch/bootstrapper/LogOutput$Level
      ... 13 more
  Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.sonar.batch.bootstrapper.LogOutput$Level
      at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
      at org.sonarsource.scanner.api.internal.IsolatedClassloader.loadClass(IsolatedClassloader.java:82)
      at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
      ... 13 more

Comment: please give more input

Comment: @SalmanS i added more details

Comment: can you help regarding : while i am execution command Sonnar-Scannar-x

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include details about your context: perhaps: scanner flavor, SonarQube version, Java version, OS of analysis machine, ...

Comment: it is already in log.. please help me regarding on that

Answer (score 4):

SonarQube Scanner 3.1.0.1141 (`19:49:25.211 INFO: SonarQube Scanner 3.1.0.1141`) is compatible with SonarQube 5.6+ (LTS) ([read more here](https://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SCAN/Analyzing+with+SonarQube+Scanner)). You have SonarQube server 5.0.1 (`19:49:25.610 INFO: SonarQube server 5.0.1`) so those two tools are incompatible (class `org/sonar/batch/bootstrapper/LogOutput$Level` has been added in 5.2).

You can:

- use an older version of the scanner ([download](http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/codehaus/sonar/runner/sonar-runner-dist/2.4/sonar-runner-dist-2.4.zip) sonar-runner 2.4 - read about [runner vs scanner](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39852490/4944847))
- upgrade SonarQube server to at least 5.6